# How use ng-repeat on ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-grid

How to use `ng-repeat` on `ui-grid` and bind attribute to ui-grid dynamically?

I was trying something like this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="group in tabledata.groups track by $index">
      <div ui-grid="gridOptions+$index" class="myGrid"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you want to achieve. It seems you want to dynamically create ui-grid but is your options array going to created dynamically ?

Comment: Yes. I want to create some ui-grids dynamically and also create dynamically ui-grid="gridOptionsX"  where X is index of grid. And next in controller I want to assign to each gridOptions1, gridOptions2..etc.  data

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you will form options for ui-grid in your controller, you can pass it as an object in your `tableData.groups` array.

So your code might return the options for each grid and this is how you can assign it to grid.

`<div ng-repeat="group in tabledata.groups track by $index">
      <div ui-grid="group" class="myGrid"></div>
 </div>`

Below is a small example of the same.

```js
var app = angular.module("gridApp", ['ui.grid']);
app.controller("gridCntrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
  
  $scope.tabledata = {};
  
  // Data 1
    $scope.resultData0 =  [{
            name: "Tom",
            country: "US"
        },
              {
            name: "Jerry",
            country: "UK"
        },
              {
            name: "Mickey",
            country: "IND"
        }];
  
  // Options 1
    $scope.options0 = {
        data: 'resultData0',
        columnDefs: [{
            field: 'name',
            displayName: "Name"
        },
         {
            field: 'country',
            displayName: "Country"
        }]
       
    }
    
    // Data 2
    $scope.resultData1 =  [{
            capital: "Washington DC",
            country: "US"
        },
              {
            capital: "London",
            country: "UK"
        },
              {
            capital: "New Delhi",
            country: "IND"
        }];
  
  // Options 2
    $scope.options1 = {
        data: 'resultData1',
        columnDefs: [{
            field: 'country',
            displayName: "Country"
        },
         {
            field: 'capital',
            displayName: "Capital"
        }]
      }
    
    $scope.tabledata.groups = [$scope.options0, $scope.options1]
}]);
```

```css
.ui-grid-style {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.js"></script>

<div class="container" ng-app = "gridApp">
    <div ng-controller="gridCntrl">
      <div class="row" ng-repeat="group in tabledata.groups">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div ui-grid="group" class="ui-grid-style"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write

`<div ui-grid="gridOptions[$index]" class="myGrid"></div>`

and in the controller, define $scope.gridOptions[0], $scope.gridOptions[1] etc.

Comment: Hi, I tried this way for one of my work. The scenario is like having multiple ui-grid in single page. I have an editable cell in column for each grid. When I edit cell for grid-1, the other grid-2 cell is also appending the values. Means they work link two-way binded. I want them to be independent grids. How can it be resolved?